# How do I flip the most significant bit in MIPS?

Tags: mips

I am trying to convert a number in 2's complement in MIPS to sign magnitude. To do this, I think I would:

1. subtract 1
2. 'Not' the word
3. Flip the most significant bit

For example, `11111111111111111111111111111001` (`0xfffffff9`) would become `00000000000000000000000000000111` (`0x00000007`).

I figured out how to do step 1 & 2, but can't figure out step 3. Does anyone know how I would do this?

Also, is there a better way to convert from 2's complement to sign magnitude format in MIPS?

Comment: Note you want to do these operations only for *negative* 2sC values (other than -2^(n-1) which has no s&m or 1sC equivalent); doing them on a positive value gives a very wrong result, and doing them on (2sC) zero gives s&m negative zero where positive zero is canonical. IME not then increment is more common than decrement then not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you XOR the value with `0x80000000`, the most significant bit will flip. You can do the last two steps (retaining the most significant bit and flipping the others) by XOR'ing with `0x7fffffff`.